# TypeError: _fire__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.auth is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I've created a login page to my app using firebase authentication. then i've a contact/personal info form which takes images and files as input and uploads them to firebase storage. but i'm facing this issue. This is my first project using react and firebase - would appreciate some simple explanation.

here is my `fire.js` file

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/storage";


if (!firebase.apps.length) {
    var fire,storage = firebase.initializeApp({
   
    // my credentials //
    });
  
 }else {
   fire = firebase.app();
   storage = firebase.storage(); // if already initialized, use that one
 }


//const fire = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export default {storage,fire};
```

and here is the page in which I'm trying to add a contact document and then add images to firebase storage:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { storage } from "./firebase";
import fire from './fire';


const AddRecord = () => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("");
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  const handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
      setImage(e.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  const handleUpload = () => {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(image);
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      snapshot => {
        const progress = Math.round(
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        );
        setProgress(progress);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        storage
          .ref("images")
          .child(image.name)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then(url => {
            setUrl(url);
          });
      }
    );
  };

  console.log("image: ", image);

  return (
    <div>
      <progress value={progress} max="100" />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
      <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
      <br />
      {url}
      <br />
      <img src={url || "http://via.placeholder.com/300"} alt="firebase-image" />
    </div>
  );
};
export default AddRecord;
```